# Create 2-d array with column keys and row keys in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I am trying to create this data structure in Python:
[2-d array structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c907.jpg)

There have to be **column keys** and **row keys** that I will be using later.
Column keys and row keys are random numbers.

For now I have this code:

```
import random

cols, rows = 5, 5 
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)]

set_col = 0
for row in Matrix:
    row[set_col] = random.randint(1,2)

columnKeys = random.sample(range(1,5), 4)
Matrix[0] = columnKeys

for row in Matrix:
    print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is not quite what I want. For now each cell value have zero. But later it will have some relevant data and I will be using this data along with **corresponding** row and column keys. I don't know how to correctly organize this data structure so I can use cell values with corresponding row/column keys.

---

How to do it **without** **Pandas** and **Numpy** so I can use column and row keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

The best way is probably *not* to use nested lists, but instead to use dictionaries. Since you mentioned pandas, the pandas DataFrame objects have a [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) function that will convert a DataFrame into a dictionary, and there are several options depending on what you prefer.

I see from your example that you are trying to create your data structure with duplicate indices.  The best option here is likely to use the structure created by running `df.to_dict("split")`.

Say your DataFrame (df) looks like this:

```
      3  1  2  4
   2  0  0  0  0
   1  0  0  0  0
   2  0  0  0  0
   1  0  0  0  0
```

Running `df.to_dict("split") will then do this:

```
d = df.to_dict("split")
{
  'columns': [3, 1, 2, 4],
  'data': [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
  'index': [2, 1, 2, 1]
}
```

Accessing data in this scenario, and in the one shown by @Makiflow is tricky.  Even within Pandas, having duplicate indices or columns on your Dataframe makes operations more interesting.  In this case, selecting `df['data'][3][1]` picks the second element in the third list contained by the `data` key.  That is actually selecting the 4th row and the 2nd column of your matrix.  If you want to be able to reference items by the column *name*, you have to do a little more leg work.

You can run `col_num = d['columns'].index(3)` which will give you the index value of the element `3`, but doing `d['index'].index(2)` will always give you 0, even if wanted to select 2 at index 3.  That's because `index()` returns the index of the first value that matches the condition.  You can of course simply select by the (col,row) index tuples, but that defeats the purpose of having column names and index values in the first place.

If you want to generate this structure without pandas, you can run:
    COLS, ROWS = 5, 5
    columns = [random.randint(0,COLS) for _ in range(COLS)]
    rows = [random.randint(1,2) for _ in range(ROWS)]

```
d = {"columns": columns,
     "index":   rows,
     "data":    [[0 for _ in range(COLS)] for _ in range(ROWS)]
    }
```

IMHO - a better solution would actually be to force your data structure to have unique index and columns values. The default output of `to_dict()` will output a very simply dictionary:

```
d = df.to_dict() # also the same as df.to_dict("dict")
{
  1: {1: 0, 2: 0}, 
  2: {1: 0, 2: 0}, 
  3: {1: 0, 2: 0}, 
  4: {1: 0, 2: 0}
}
```

In this configuration, each key to the dictionary is the name of a column.  Each of those keys points to another dicitonary that represents the information in that column - each key is an index value, followed by the value.

This likely makes the most intuitive sense because if you wanted to get the value at the column *named* 3 at the index *named* 1, you would do:

```
   d = df.to_dict()
   d[3][1]
   # 0
```

You can create this data structure without using Pandas quite simply:

```
COLS, ROWS = 5,5 
rows = [i for i in range(ROWS)]
columns = [i for in range(COLS)]
{c : {i:0 for i in rows} for c in columns}
# {
#  0: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
#  1: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
#  2: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
#  3: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
#  4: {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
# }
```

It's really dependent on the constraints/requirements that you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

COLS, ROWS = 5, 5 
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(COLS)] for y in range(ROWS)]

set_col = 0
for row in Matrix:
    row[set_col] = random.randint(1,2)

columnKeys = random.sample(range(1,5), 4)
Matrix[0] = [0] + columnKeys

for row in Matrix:
    print(row)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 3, 1, 2, 4]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```